# Insert multiple values and ignore duplicates on not key field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

If I want to insert multiple values to a table with fields:

```
ID | name | content  
---+------+------------------
 1 | john | some content  
 2 | bob  | another content
```

and now I want to insert multiple values:

```
INSERT INTO persons (name,content)
VALUES
("Foo","meh"),
("Moo","beh"),
("bob","huh"),
("dude","haha")
```

that the result should be:

```
ID | name | content  
---+------+------------------
 1 | john | some content  
 2 | bob  | another content
 3 | Foo  | meh
 4 | Moo  | beh
 5 | dude | haha
```

The query ignores duplicates by name so "bob"|"huh" is not inserted, the name is not a key field. I can't find anywhere the syntax for this, I know it should be something simple.

I'm using MySQL database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to determine if record is already in table

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ebe45/1/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE persons(ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      name VARCHAR(100),
      content VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO persons (name, content)
VALUES ('john', 'some content'), ('bob', 'another content');

INSERT INTO persons (name,content)
SELECT t.name, t.content
FROM
(
  SELECT "Foo" AS name,"meh" AS content
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "Moo","beh"
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "bob","huh"
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "dude","haha"
) AS t
LEFT JOIN persons p
ON p.name = t.name
WHERE p.id IS NULL;

SELECT *
FROM persons;
```

Same using `NOT EXISTS`

```
INSERT INTO persons (name,content)
SELECT t.name, t.content
FROM
(
  SELECT "Foo" AS name,"meh" AS content
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "Moo","beh"
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "bob","huh"
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "dude","haha"
) AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
     (SELECT 1 FROM persons p WHERE p.name = t.name)
```

**EDIT:**

Add `UNIQUE KEY` and use `INSERT IGNORE INTO`

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2002e/1/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE persons(ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      name VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE KEY,
      content VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO persons (name, content)
VALUES ('john', 'some content'), ('bob', 'another content');


INSERT IGNORE INTO persons (name,content)
VALUES
("Foo","meh"),
("Moo","beh"),
("bob","huh"),
("dude","haha");

SELECT *
FROM persons;
```

Comment: I would also recommend adding a UNIQUE INDEX/KEY to prevent the table from having more than one person with the same name.

Comment: @lad2025 and uri thanks very much. I ussed lad2025's second answer, which worked perfectly, and works perfect if you really don't want to touch your table structure, but the better way is to set UNIQUE KEY on this field as you both said, and for the future i am going to use it. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is in tsql but you could create a stored procedure with a merge statement that has a table type (name and content as columns) as a parameter to check the name before inserting. If the name matches then it will not insert but if it doesn't match then it will insert a new record.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- setup tables for merge
MERGE dbo.persons AS t

USING @NameContentTable AS s
    ON t.name = s.name      

-- do nothing if matched

-- insert if not matched
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
    INSERT (name, 
            content)
    VALUES (s.name,
            s.content);

-- error handling
IF @@ERROR <> 0 
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Unexpected error occurred'
    ROLLBACK TRAN 
    RETURN -1
END

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: thank you @hines, I'm using mysql so i assume for tsql your answer is good :), have a nice day!